# dynamic numeric PHP increacing div id

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I am using this script:

```
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/
```

I am using it to create a dynamic WordPress costume post type category display. I managed to present the categories dynamicly but I need to create some kind of a dynamic numeric id for every category that is edded.
Also, I need the DIV with the categody content (I will add a list of posts there) to be created dynamicly.

This is some of the code:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
<?php

$taxonomy = 'portfolio_categories';
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy); // Get all terms of a taxonomy

if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
?>


<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
            <li><a href="#tabs-<?php here i need the dynamic numeric ID ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
i need this to be created dynamicly like the foreach
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
i need this to be created dynamicly like the foreach

  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
so on and so on..
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an incrementing counter to the loop:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <?php $counter = 0; ?>
        <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
            <li><a href="#tabs-<?php echo $counter; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
            <?php $counter++; ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <?php $counter = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
        <div id="tabs-<?php echo $counter; ?>">
            i need this to be created dynamicly like the foreach
        </div>
        <?php $counter++; ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! we are half way in. and how will i show a post list from the specific "$term->name;" ?